# IE11 - Toggling a Class via jQuery.toggleClass() Doesn't Activate the Class in IE11 - It Works in All Other Browsers

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

This works in all browsers except IE 11.

My code is pretty basic.

Click on the text to toggle the class "infinite" which (should) loop the bounce effect forever.

IE11 applies the class to the H1 tag but it doesn't animate infinitely like it does in all other browsers.

The intended behavior is for it to bounce once at load (this works) and clicking the text applies the class "infinite" which (should) makes it bounce forever (this doesn't work in IE 11).

```js
 $(window).ready(function(){
  $('h1').on('click',function(){
   $('h1').toggleClass('infinite');
  });
 });
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="bounce animated">Example</h1>
```

I am on Windows 7 with IE 11.0.9600.17239

Here is another example with all classes applied at start which works:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h1 class="animated bounce infinite">Example</h1>
```

**After posting the second example, this makes me believe this is a jQuery issue of some type combined with IE 11...**

Comment: i just tried it in ie11 on w8.1 works fine

Comment: @saj - Interesting.  I'm on Windows 7.  I'll add that to the description.  Thank you.

Comment: On win 8.1 with IE 11.0.18, does not work for me. The class is set/removed on click but no bounce effect

Comment: @Yoann - I wonder if saj was mistaken that it was working correctly.  saj were you able to toggle the infinite bounce?  Not just a single bounce that happens when it first runs.

Comment: I cant post an image in the comments nice, i'm on 11.0.9600.17728, x64 update version 11.0.18 (kb30338314)

Comment: It animates not infinitely tho, It bounces a couple of time in ie and chrome eh?

Comment: When you click on the title in chrome it should bounce inifinetely

Comment: @saj - Ok, so it is not working properly then.  It does the initial bounce, but after clicking the text it is supposed to infinitely bounce and never stop.

Comment: Do you have the code for the bounce @keyframes?

Comment: hope i didn't mix u up bud, it's doing as you describe and animating on click in chrome but not in ie11, the infinite class does not seem to applying i did try adding it manually no effect, but not sure if the snippet thing is causing

Comment: i am using ie 11 on window 7.  it works fine !!

Comment: @Yoann, I added another example without JavaScript with classes applied from the start.  This works in IE11.

Comment: It is not jquery, tried in vanilla, does not work either. https://jsfiddle.net/dqgvvnrj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but it gets the job done:

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
    var el = $('h1');

    el.on('click',function(){
        el.removeClass('bounce animated');
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.toggleClass('bounce animated infinite');
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="bounce animated">Example</h1>
```

It seems like IE does not cooperate when setting the "animation-iteration-count" after an animation has previously finished. This will remove and re-add the classes to ensure the animation completes.

Comment: You got it!  I wonder why this is the case only for IE and how I can find out more information on this.  This "bug" has been killing me for hours.  Thank you!

Comment: Found some additional information on why this happens, but not specifically why for IE11 only: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/