# toggleClass not working in IE or Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of jquery  which expands a hidden selection of text when clicked it also changes the drop down arrow to face the other way when clicked.

Here is an example -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-1").click(function(){
        $("#div-1").toggle(1000);
  $("#arrow-1").toggleClass("up");
    });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle-2").click(function(){
        $("#div-2").toggle(1000);
  $("#arrow-2").toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

```css
   body {text-align:center}
      
      p {text-align:left}
      
      a.toggle-1 {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
      a.toggle-1:hover {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}
      
      a.toggle-2 {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
      a.toggle-2:hover {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}
      
      .arrow:after {font-weight:bold; content:"  ⮛";}
      
   .arrow.up:after {font-weight:bold; content:"  ⮙";}
      

      #div-1 {display:none}
      #div-2 {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Welcome</h2>


<a class="toggle-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Here<span id="arrow-1" class="arrow"></span></a>


<div id="div-1">
<p>Proin ultricies dolor dapibus, ornare dolor sed, commodo lectus. Suspendisse aliquet placerat ante et elementum. Fusce eleifend erat sit amet massa sollicitudin sodales. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed vitae diam eget nisi fringilla vehicula. Integer ac ipsum tincidunt, imperdiet risus et, viverra sem. Suspendisse urna erat, interdum sed justo vitae, aliquet viverra arcu. Curabitur in vulputate dolor. Proin neque nunc, condimentum id sollicitudin ac, vehicula eu neque. Morbi pharetra sagittis erat non pellentesque. Nullam quis blandit ex, vitae dapibus nibh. Nullam porttitor velit nisi, at dictum tortor dictum a.</p>
</div>

<div style="clear:left;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px"></div>

<a class="toggle-2" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Here too!<span id="arrow-2" class="arrow"></span></a>

<div id="div-2">

<p>Morbi ut rhoncus mauris, nec vestibulum eros. Aenean tincidunt consectetur lacus at ultrices. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur quis accumsan leo. Nam in leo ex. Quisque quis porttitor quam, non porttitor lacus. Proin eget nisl libero. Suspendisse efficitur pretium neque sed rhoncus. Proin hendrerit efficitur mi vitae ullamcorper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur nec lorem pretium, venenatis tortor id, imperdiet lorem. Praesent maximus ipsum ante, scelerisque malesuada mauris cursus ut. Pellentesque nunc massa, varius vel egestas sed, mollis eget lorem. Etiam tempor luctus faucibus. Phasellus fringilla vel augue ornare gravida.</p>
</div>
```

The code seems to work fine, but only if I use Firefox or Chrome.

Every time I try using Microsoft Edge or IE, the div expands, but the class toggle does not work, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE 6/7/8, use jQuery 1.0 library

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203595/ie11-toggling-a-class-via-jquery-toggleclass-doesnt-activate-the-class-in-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `content` in such a way that both values doesn't have the same pattern:

For example:

```
.arrow:after {content:"⮛";} 
.arrow.up:after {content:" ⮙";}
```

Add an empty space character before `content` value in any of the above will make it work in IE browsers as well.

In your code you have spaces before in both cases so because of same number of spaces (similar pattern) its not working.

I'm not sure about the reason behind such behavior of IE. May be its a bug or something else however doing so will make it working in IE browsers.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle-1").click(function(){
      $("#div-1").toggle(1000);
  $("#arrow-1").toggleClass("up");
  });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle-2").click(function(){
      $("#div-2").toggle(1000);
  $("#arrow-2").toggleClass("up");
  });
});
```

```css
body {text-align:center}

p {text-align:left}

a.toggle-1 {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
a.toggle-1:hover {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}

a.toggle-2 {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
a.toggle-2:hover {font-size:1.5em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;}

.arrow:after {font-weight:bold; content:"⮛";}

.arrow.up:after {font-weight:bold; content:" ⮙";}


#div-1 {display:none}
#div-2 {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porttitor felis dui, nec hendrerit erat condimentum non. Sed orci eros, volutpat vitae nisi et, auctor sodales libero. Maecenas dignissim augue eget orci euismod, eu maximus felis vehicula. Etiam ut elit pharetra, gravida metus at, lacinia sapien. Aliquam non est ut dui dictum hendrerit. Cras condimentum ante purus. Vivamus volutpat vel mauris vel molestie. Nulla nec fringilla enim. Nunc sed mi eleifend, viverra mi at, pretium nibh. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut at dapibus mauris. Morbi volutpat vitae lacus ut tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam et lectus feugiat, tempor nunc et, aliquam augue.</p>

<a class="toggle-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Here<span id="arrow-1" class="arrow"></span></a>


<div id="div-1">
<p> Proin ultricies dolor dapibus, ornare dolor sed, commodo lectus. Suspendisse aliquet placerat ante et elementum. Fusce eleifend erat sit amet massa sollicitudin sodales. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed vitae diam eget nisi fringilla vehicula. Integer ac ipsum tincidunt, imperdiet risus et, viverra sem. Suspendisse urna erat, interdum sed justo vitae, aliquet viverra arcu. Curabitur in vulputate dolor. Proin neque nunc, condimentum id sollicitudin ac, vehicula eu neque. Morbi pharetra sagittis erat non pellentesque. Nullam quis blandit ex, vitae dapibus nibh. Nullam porttitor velit nisi, at dictum tortor dictum a.

Donec eu consequat ex, eu dapibus lectus. Suspendisse sit amet sapien sed quam mollis condimentum. Maecenas ullamcorper volutpat facilisis. Sed eget porta purus, ac fermentum erat. Cras tincidunt, mi vel scelerisque consectetur, ligula urna scelerisque justo, quis commodo tellus purus sit amet velit. Nam accumsan, odio ut ullamcorper luctus, nisi risus iaculis massa, a mollis ante eros vel nibh. Sed et orci tincidunt, suscipit erat non, rutrum urna. </p>
</div>

<div style="clear:left;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px"></div>

<a class="toggle-2" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Here too!<span id="arrow-2" class="arrow"></span></a>

<div id="div-2">
<p> Morbi ut rhoncus mauris, nec vestibulum eros. Aenean tincidunt consectetur lacus at ultrices. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur quis accumsan leo. Nam in leo ex. Quisque quis porttitor quam, non porttitor lacus. Proin eget nisl libero. Suspendisse efficitur pretium neque sed rhoncus. Proin hendrerit efficitur mi vitae ullamcorper. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur nec lorem pretium, venenatis tortor id, imperdiet lorem. Praesent maximus ipsum ante, scelerisque malesuada mauris cursus ut. Pellentesque nunc massa, varius vel egestas sed, mollis eget lorem. Etiam tempor luctus faucibus. Phasellus fringilla vel augue ornare gravida.

Praesent lobortis in lacus at bibendum. Sed sed condimentum nibh, vitae molestie velit. Ut convallis ex leo, non congue mauris faucibus vel. Morbi dictum aliquam purus, at blandit magna commodo nec. Mauris euismod ipsum magna, sit amet tempor sem interdum vitae. Maecenas ac urna enim. Aliquam elementum velit quis tortor ornare, eget eleifend sapien facilisis. Mauris euismod lectus a placerat dictum. Ut pellentesque imperdiet magna eget ultrices. Duis auctor lorem at nulla ultricies finibus. Mauris sagittis placerat est et lobortis. Nulla placerat convallis erat, in consequat est dignissim vel.

Ut aliquet nisi quam, et pretium sem tempor hendrerit. Nam venenatis sapien in porttitor molestie. Curabitur vel massa vel tellus euismod gravida in ornare urna. Morbi hendrerit nisi ut odio ultrices, eget lobortis mauris euismod. Maecenas rhoncus finibus dictum. Donec quis augue sed elit aliquam varius. Vestibulum placerat feugiat risus at porttitor. Phasellus vel imperdiet massa, et porta justo. Nunc interdum justo at vehicula vehicula.

Proin ut turpis imperdiet, luctus orci a, convallis turpis. Morbi pellentesque metus a mi volutpat, faucibus accumsan turpis congue. Proin rutrum, libero non lacinia eleifend, neque eros aliquet ex, eu sagittis augue purus eget nulla. Quisque placerat lacus vitae libero pretium, nec ultrices quam efficitur. Sed lobortis risus id semper aliquam. Sed finibus nibh maximus, lobortis neque fermentum, pulvinar ex. Cras finibus metus a nunc pellentesque venenatis vel bibendum sapien. Vestibulum laoreet est a arcu tempor pellentesque. Quisque sit amet quam felis.

Phasellus lacus sapien, pulvinar vel vulputate sed, molestie non turpis. Donec at placerat leo, vel auctor enim. Maecenas accumsan ex in neque sodales, pretium malesuada nunc ullamcorper. Donec pharetra, diam ac congue ultrices, nibh tellus fringilla magna, sed vehicula eros ligula sed mauris. Nam elementum scelerisque vehicula. Curabitur condimentum mi ut velit auctor, id cursus ante condimentum. Cras iaculis mattis dignissim. Nullam fringilla imperdiet ante, at luctus ipsum accumsan vel. In pharetra odio et dapibus consectetur. Donec vel euismod tortor. Maecenas vitae facilisis orci. Curabitur orci turpis, pulvinar sit amet justo accumsan, vulputate lacinia dolor. </p>
```

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple haha! Thanks for your help.